# Using environment variables in Kubernetes deployment spec

Tags: environment-variables, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I currently use a Kubernetes spec `Deployment.yaml` for deploying a service. The spec includes a verbatim reference to a specific IP address (marked as `<static-ip-address>` below):

```
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: <static-ip-address>
```

I am concerned about pushing information such as passwords or IP addresses into remote Git repositories. Can I avoid this e.g. by making use of environment variables, e.g. with a deployment spec and actual deployment roughly as follows:

```
spec:
   type: LoadBalancer
   loadBalancerIP: ${SERVICE_ADDRESS}
```

and

```
export SERVICE_ADDRESS=<static-ip-address>
kubectl create -f Deployment.yaml
```

Obviously this specific syntax does not work yet. But is something like this possible and if so how?

I'd prefer not relying on a separate [provisioning tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33480850/1789384). [Secret](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/secrets/)s and [`ConfigMap`](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/configmap/)s seem promising, but apparently they cannot be consumed in a way that suits this purpose. If I could directly reference a static IP address that was defined with `gcloud compute addresses create service-address` that would be best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was another pleasantly simple solution: I have a Google Compute Address `my-address` defined, and I can apparently use it in the service spec like so: `loadBalancerIP: my-address`.

With this as "external" source for IP addresses and secrets for passwords there is no more need for a provisioning tool (or templates) for my simple use case (within a GKE environment).

**OBSOLETE NOW:** I have decided on using a provisioning tool of sorts, namely "built-in" `sed`, after all.

My `Deployment.yaml` now contains a "template variable" e.g. in

```
loadBalancerIP: $$EXTERNAL_IP
```

and I deploy the service with, say, 1.2.3.4 as external IP address with

```
cat Deployment.yaml | sed s/\$\$EXTERNAL_IP/1.2.3.4/ | kubectl create -f -
```

Comment: Jan Grewe s approach is more generic an can be applied to any number of variables. I would suggest do accept his answer instead of accepting your own that is less generic and needs to be adjusted for every additional variable.

Answer (score 34):

A much easier/cleaner solution: `envsubst`

In deploy.yml:

```
LoadbalancerIP: $LBIP
```

Then just create your env var and run kubectl like this:

```
export LBIP="1.2.3.4"
envsubst < deploy.yml | kubectl apply -f -
```

You just put regular Bash variables into whatever file you want to use, in this case the YAML manifest, and have ensubst read that file. It will output the file with the env vars replaced by their values. You can also use it to create new files like this:

```
envsubst < input.yml > output.yml
```

`envsubst` is available in e.g. Ubuntu/Debian `gettext` package.

Comment: +1 for `envsubst`. didnt know about this until now

Comment: It's not easier/cleaner, as it requires a separate tool, which is not by default installed on all systems (e.g. Mac)

Comment: @Ivan His question was "But is something like this possible and if so how?", and that is the answer to his question. The question was not "How can i do this with tools available on every OS by default?". And yes, it is 1) easier AND 2) cleaner than using `sed`. By your definition, the proposed solution with `sed` would also not be easier/cleaner, as there is no `sed` installed on Windows machines by default.

Comment: It's not clear at all that you were comparing to "sed" option.

Comment: having gone the sed route a year ago - sed does not scale well. envsubst is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple pre-processor to do variable substitution on your yaml files (or you can use [jsonnet](http://jsonnet.org/index.html) to accomplish the same thing on json configuration files).

There is some discussion around [adding templates directly into Kubernetes configuration](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23896) but it isn't yet implemented or available.

Comment: Yes, but jsonnet is a provision tool as mentioned in the question.

Comment: If you're looking for something built-in, then following the issue I linked to is your best bet at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Until [templates](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23896) are available, the easiest way to do it is to run a job which [uses the Kubernetes API](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/accessing-the-cluster/#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod) to update the service. A short shell script in an alpine-based image, coupled with a secret (containing the IP address) and a configmap (containing the template), should be simple enough. The difficult bit is correctly using the authentication and authorization features of the apiserver.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30690186/how-do-i-access-the-kubernetes-api-from-within-a-pod-container gives an example of accessing the API. Obviously, you'll want to POST to [/api/v1/namespaces/default/services](http://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1/operations/#_create_a_service) instead of the GET in that example.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but can you please elaborate a bit more. Could you give or point to an example of a suitable shell script.